# Change default image viewer

Tags: python, images, imagemagick, defaults, feh

```
# ...

def show():
    """
    Show image
    """
    t = Twitter(auth=authen())
    try:
        target = g['stuff'].split()[0]
        if target != 'image':
            return
        id = int(g['stuff'].split()[1])
        tid = c['tweet_dict'][id]
        tweet = t.statuses.show(id=tid)
        media = tweet['entities']['media']
        for m in media:
            res = requests.get(m['media_url'])
            img = Image.open(BytesIO(res.content))
            img.show()
    except:
        debug_option()
        printNicely(red('Sorry I can\'t show this image.'))

# ...
```

This is the section of code that the developer claims will open an image with the OS's default image viewer. For me, it opens it with imagemagick but I want it to open with feh. How can I change the OS's default image viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, `PIL` defaults to using the `display` command provided by ImageMagick to display image (or `xv`, if exists).  If you want to open an image with other program, you might have to modify `PIL`'s source, and here is [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279441/image-show-wont-display-the-picture#answer-31596116).